# Grouped UITableView sticky header/footer sections

Tags: ios, header, uitableview

Is it possible to have sticky header/footer sections for a `UITableView` that is grouped?

If not, is there an alternative way of achieving this?

Comment: what exactly do u mean by sticky?

Comment: It sticks to the bottom of the view!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.

You'll have to create your own UITableViewController by subclassing a UIViewController.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12571975/672989) provides some advice on a sticky footer.. for a sticky header and footer you'll need to:

1. Have your class inherit from UIViewController (instead of UITableViewController)
2. Have your class
   implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource
   protocols
3. Implement the UITableViewDelegate and
   UITableViewDataSource methods in your class (e.g. cellForRowAtIndexPath:, didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, etc)
4. In IB, add a 
   UITableView as a subview to your view controller's view
5. Resize and move the frame of the
   UITableView to allow space at the bottom and the top for your header & footer
6. Set the
   delegate and datasource properties of the table view you just added
   to be your viewcontroller class
7. Add 2 subviews to your view controller's view one for your header and one for your footer.

Now the footer and header view are not part of the UITableView and won't scroll.